# how to configure a letsencrypt certificate for two different domains on the same vhost?

Tags: https, subdomain, lets-encrypt

**Needs:**
I have a main site **mymultisite.com** and sub-site, **sub1.mymultisite.com**
I configured them **using sub-domain** (not subfolder)
Now I need to enable HTTPS for both of them, using LetsEncrypt.

**Problems:**
I can successfully enable SSL for the main site (mymultisite.com).

But don’t know how to do with the subsite (**sub1.mymultisite.com**) yet.

**What I tried:**

1. Option 1: From Linux (Debian), run: `sudo certbot –-apache`
   => It didn’t work as there’s no actual site named **sub1.mymultisite.com**
2. Option 2: From Linux (Debian), run:

   `certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/mymultisite.com/ -d sub1.mymultisite.com`
   => It succeeded in generating the key. But when accessing the subsite from browser, it said:

   > This server could not prove that it is **sub1.mymultisite.com**; its
   >   security certificate is from **mymultisite.com**. This may be caused by a
   >   misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by:

1. From Linux, create corresponding .conf file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/subsite.mymultisite.com.conf` for each subsite.

   Value of `DocumentRoot` is same as main site’s `DocumentRoot` (Eg: `/var/www/sub1.mymainsite.com`).
2. Enable subsite using: `a2ensite`
3. Run certbot as normal. It should work.